# Are the following sentences correct and natural?

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the following sentences correct and natural? All follow the same pattern:

> 1. Vaccination campaigns are the most cost-effective of health investments.
> 2. Maths is the most important of courses.
> 3. The USA is the biggest of economies.
> 4. Cheetahs are the fastest of mammals.

I am not native and curious to know if sentences like these are poetic!? Can this pattern be used in academic context?

Comment: They all follow the same pattern but your subjects are different in each. For instance, "maths" is a British usage (in AmE, the singular is used); I'm not sure that #3 works either -- I'd use "has".

Comment: When stating a scientific or economic fact, it would be usual to say _the largest economy, the fastest mammal_ and so on.

Comment: If you're specifying a single thing you would not normally use "of", e.g. "the most famous person". Something like "the largest of ships" sounds old-fashioned or (as you say) poetic. "Of" would be used when you're dealing with a specific set: "the most famous of the Beatles" or "the most famous of sixteen people at the party".

Comment: To me, 1 is natural, 2 is acceptable, and 3 and 4 are wrong. A good answer would explain why. I have a feeling it's about how tightly the subject is associated with the noun after "of", but I'm not sure enough to write an answer